# Moving items from one listbox to another using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I basically want to move items from one listbox to another using Jquery. I am trying to do this in my MVC application.

The code commented below works but it is not what I want. So if I select an item on the source listbox it gets added to the destination listbox. I basically want the movement to happen upon click of the button. That is the    $('#ShiftRight').click(function () that i have written below. Further below you would see the two listboxes and button code. The problem that I am facing is when I click the button, the item moves to the destination for a second and goes back the source again. Could someone tell me why this is happening ?

```
//$('#sourceItems').change(function () {
//    $('#sourceItems option:selected').appendTo('#destinationItems');
//});

$('#ShiftRight').click(function () {
    $('#sourceItems option:selected').appendTo('#destinationItems');
});
```

```html
<div class="Row">
    <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
        <p>@Html.Label("List of Recipients")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:top">
        @Html.ListBox("sourceItems", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UserList, new { @style = "width: 250px;height: 130px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="borderlessCell" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <p><input type="submit" id="ShiftRight" value=">>" /> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" id="ShiftLeft" value="<<" /></p>
    </div>

    <div class="borderlessCell">
        @Html.ListBox("destinationItems", new SelectList(new[] { "" }), new { @style = "width: 250px;height: 130px;" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it appears to re-appear in the original list is because you are using a submit button, which is causing a postback of the form. Change the `input type="submit"` to a plain button:

```
<p><button id="ShiftRight">&gt;&gt;</button></p>
<p><button id="ShiftLeft">&lt;&lt;</button></p>
```